# Please tell me why this code is not working

Tags: c

This program will determine the count, minimum, maximum, sum and average of all valid numbers entered. It will stop asking for new values when zero is entered and don't accept negative values. After asking for 1st number it just stops working. I will be very happy if anyone can give me some tips how to write it more efficiently and some for just coding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void display(void);


void menu(void);

int main(void)

{
    display();
    menu();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void display(void)
{
    printf("program will determine the count, minimum, maximum, sum and average of all valid numbers entered.\n");
    return;
}

void menu(void)
{
    int count;
    float min = 0;
    float max = 0;
    float sum;
    float avg;
    float user = 0;
    int index;

    printf("Please enter the number ==> ");
    do
    {
// I think I scew up here plz check it.
        scanf("%f", user);
        if (user > 0)
        {
            if (user > max)
            {
                max = user;
            }
            if (user < min)
            {
                min = user;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please enter a positive number");
        }
        sum += user;
        count = index;
        index++;
    } while (user != 0);

    avg = sum / count;

    printf("The minimum number ==> %f", min);
    printf("The maximum number ==> %f", max);
    printf("The number of enteries ==> %i", count);
    printf("The sum of all values ==> %f", sum);
    printf("The average of all values ==> %f", avg);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The title has almost no value for future visitors. Can you edit it to clearly describe the problem? Thanks.

Comment: `count` and `sum` must be initialized to zero, and initializing `min` to zero is not a good idea.

Comment: why min should not be zero??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `scanf("%f", user);` should be `scanf("%f", &user);`
2. You'd not want to increase these if input - `user` is not correct:

   ```
   sum += user;
   count = index;
   index++;
   ```

   Moreover, your `count` is not being computed correctly. To be specific, you're calculating 1 less than actual count. So put this block inside `if` statement like this

   ```
   if (user > 0)
   {
       if (user > max)
       {
           max = user;
       }
       if (user < min)
       {
           min = user;
       }
       sum += user;
       count = index + 1;
       index++;
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Please enter a positive number");
   }
   ```
3. Be cautious when using `%i`. `%d` and `%i` are same when used in `printf` but not in `scanf`.

   ```
   printf("The number of enteries ==> %d", count); //Notice %d
   ```

Comment: "**Use %d for int instead of %i.**" Why? `%d` and `%i` are the same when used in `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
scanf("%f", user);
```

You are not storing the input into `user`. You can fix it like this:

```
scanf("%f", &user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your error:

```
scanf("%f", user);
```

The `%f` format specifier to `scanf` expects the *address* of a `float`, i.e. a `float *`.  All function parameters in C are pass by value, meaning that changing a parameter isn't reflected in the calling function.  By passing a pointer, the function can dereference the pointer to write to the location it points to.

So change the function call to pass in the address of `user`:

```
scanf("%f", &user);
```

Comment: please explain more, I am new so some things just have gone over my head.